# Spline, B-Spline and NURBS C++ library

Tags: c++, graphics

Does anyone know of a library or set of classes for splines - specifically b-splines and NURBS (optional).

A fast, efficient b-spline library would be so useful for me at the moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.) For B Splines - You should check Numerical Recipes in C (there is book for that and it is also available online for reference)

2.) Also check: [sourceforge.net/projects/einspline/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/einspline/)
& [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/bspline.html)

-AD

Comment: The numerical recipes in C code used to fall under a fairly draconian license.  Not sure if this is still the case, but but be advised that it may be illegal to use it in open-source projects (I'm not an expert on this though)

Comment: Numerical Recipes doesn't have anything on B-Splines.

Answer (score 18):

I know I'm answering months after this question was asked, but for others who might be searching for a similar answer, I'll point out [openNURBS](http://www.opennurbs.org/).

OpenNURBS also happens to be the library used in the modeling package [Rhinoceros](http://www.rhino3d.com/). It's a very complete library and it's worth consideration.

Comment: Thanks man! If I hadn't marked an answer already, OpenNurbs would probably deserve it.

Comment: Understood. Just hoped to make the answers more complete. :)

Comment: I think openNURBS takes care only of saving to/opening from the .3dm format; it does not actually perform geometrical operations. For that, as is mentioned in the link, Rhino SDK is needed, which is proprietary tech.

Answer (score 3):

This library may also be promising: http://libnurbs.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

[Eigen Spline](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__Splines__Module.html) is based on the famous (fast) C++ template library for linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Also ITK has a class for bspline itkBSplineScatteredDataPointSetToImageFilter 
see example at http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/WishList/PointSet/BSplineScatteredDataPointSetToImageFilter
( documentation at http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BSplineScatteredDataPointSetToImageFilter.html 
http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BSplineScatteredDataPointSetToImageFilter.html
)

Answer (score 1):

An excellent library that is also supplemented by an online book is from MIT. Here is the (hyper)book 
http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/mathe.html

and in the bottom of the link you will find the related software, here: 
http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/software.html

GSL has a nice very basic b-spline implementation, but it does not include NURBS curves neither algorithms for inserting/removing knots, or several more advanced things. You can also find many useful algorithms that you can compile in your own language in the book, "The NURBS book", Piegl & Tiller, this one: 
[http://www.amazon.com/NURBS-Book-Monographs-Visual-Communication/dp/3540615458](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540615458)

Numerical Recipes do not include support for b-splines.

Answer (score 0):

[SISL](https://github.com/SINTEF-Geometry/SISL) seems to be a good NURBS library (under the AGPL licence). It is part of [GoTools](http://www.sintef.no/Geometry-Toolkits) which can be cloned [here](https://github.com/SINTEF-Geometry/GoTools).

Answer (score 0):

[vspline](https://bitbucket.org/kfj/vspline) is a free, open source B-spline library. It's comprehensive and fast, with additional code to efficiently process nD raster data like images and volumes. It's header-only C++ template metacode in C++11 standard, with few external dependencies. There is also a debian package of the same name.