# Two point boundary with odeint

Tags: c++, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations, odeint

I am trying to solve two point boundary problem with odeint. My equation has the form of

```
y'' + a*y' + b*y + c = 0
```

It is pretty trivial when I have boundary conditions of `y(x_1) = y_1 , y'(x_2) = y_2`, but when boundary conditions are `y(x_1) = y_1 , y(x_2) = y_2` I am lost. Does anybody know the way to deal with problems like this with odeint or other scientific library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need a shooting method. odeint does not have such a method, it solved the initial value problem (IVP) which is your first case. I think in the Numerical Recipies this method is explained and you can use Boost.Odeint to do the time stepping.

Comment: It seemed so for me as well, but I thought that odeint might have it -- it's just my problem that I cannot find it. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and more efficient method to solve this type of problem is finite differences or finite elements method. For finite differences you can check Numerical Recipes. For finite elements I recommend dealii library.

Another approach is to use b-splines: Assuming you do know the initial x0 and final xfinal points of integration, then you can expand the solution y(x) in a b-spline basis, defined over (x0,xfinal), i.e.

```
y(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n A_i*B_i(x),
```

where A_i are constant coefficients to be determined, and B_i(x) are b-spline basis (well defined polynomial functions, that can be differentiated numerically). For scientific applications you can find an implementation of b-splines in GSL.

With this substitution the boundary value problem is reduced to a linear problem, since (am using Einstein summation for repeated indices):

```
A_i*[ B_i''(x) + a*B_i'(x) + b*B_i(x)] + c =0
```

You can choose a set of points x and create a linear system from the above equation. You can find information for this type of method in the following review paper "Applications of B-splines in Atomic and Molecular Physics"  - H Bachau, E Cormier, P Decleva, J E Hansen and F Martín

http://iopscience.iop.org/0034-4885/64/12/205/

I do not know of any library solving directly this problem, but there are several libraries for B-splines (I recommend GSL for your needs), that will allow you to form the linear system. See this stackoverflow question: 
[Spline, B-Spline and NURBS C++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327218/spline-b-spline-and-nurbs-c-library/27119586#27119586)