# B-spline curve with n control points and order k in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, video-processing, smoothing, bspline

I have some 1D points and now I want to fit it into a curve. By chance, a suggestion is to use B-spline curve.
I want to create B-spline curve from some n control points (some 1D points) and order (degree) k by using code C++. Could Can anyone suggest me any sample code in C++ or guide/ explain link, please? Thank you in advance.

Here is illustrate figure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [Spline, B-Spline and NURBS C++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327218/spline-b-spline-and-nurbs-c-library) from Stack Overflow or [GNU Scientific Library – Reference Manual: Example programs for B-splines](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-B_002dsplines.html)

(A simple search in Google)

Comment: if it helped - kindly approve my answer

Comment: Require 15 reputation to vote up for you. I only have 11 reputation. I can not. Sorry about that. And for the above link, it is so complicated for me. I have not ever use GNU library. It is diff for me to read it. Could you suggest simple library?

Comment: @user2745692 - click on the "V" sign. try to search in google