# smoothing rough edges contour opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, blending

I have this image

[image]

when you zoom it you can see the rough edges like this

[image]

I want to smoothen the rough edges such that they form an almost perfect curve/line,some what like this
[image]

I tried this method
[Image edge smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795643/image-edge-smoothing-with-opencv)
But I can't seem to save it as a bmp file. I tried Gaussian blur too but didn't get any much affect. The outlines are contours extracted from a binary image. Increasing the thickness of the contours removes the rough edges to a point but it changes the clear definition of the boundaries.

EDIT:-How about filled binary images?

This

[image]

to

[image]

Dilating would change the boundary too much.

Comment: You can't do that with _digital_ images. Your limit is the pixel. You can do anti-aliasing, but it's just a visual effect.

Comment: if thickening border is what you want (inference from 2nd pic and 3rd pic,as the one pixel you want to be expanded to other pixel in the near-by region, say nearby 2 pixels), you can go for morphological operations, probably dialations would be good in your case
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: how about the filled image as shown in my edited question?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is not possible in the manner you are thinking of. As @Miki stated, Digital images have an upper limit of resolution that you can not go further than it.

The solution is to represent your curves as vectorized curves. Then you can render at any resolution you want. One possible solution is to use [Bezier Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to represent the contours (or [Spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics))). Then you may simply draw them with any resize fraction you want.

Here you can find some resources:

- [Are there any good libraries for solving cubic splines in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204553/are-there-any-good-libraries-for-solving-cubic-splines-in-c)
- [Spline, B-Spline and NURBS C++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327218/spline-b-spline-and-nurbs-c-library)
- [OpenCV - Fit a curve to a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898881/opencv-fit-a-curve-to-a-set-of-points)

Comment: how about the filled image as shown in my edited question?